# Rekognition timestamps for when objects stop being detected

Tags: video, face-detection, amazon-rekognition

For a research project I've been using AWS rekognition to detect faces in a short film. I am hoping to be able to make an index of epochs for the length of time that a given shot of a face in the movie is onscreen (e.g., if there's a scene where a face appears at a certain shot, it is first detected at timestamp *a* and stops being detected at timestamp *b*, culminating in a duration of *y* that that specific shot of the face is in the movie).

While rekognition provides timestamps for when a face or object is first detected onscreen, I can't seem to find a way to know at what timestamp the given face is no longer on-screen and stops being detected (i.e., the label's 'offset time').

Is there a way to retrieve 'offset time' data from rekognition? Or is there some other way I would have to get it?

Answer (score 0):

There are GetPersonTracking and StartFaceSearch API that can track the face.
See

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/API_GetPersonTracking.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/API_StartFaceSearch.html

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful! Do you know if it would also work to run GetFaceDetection on the movie with a reverse effect? That way shouldn't the timestamp provided in the reverse direction represent the last millisecond the face was on screen in the regular direction?

Comment: The Rekognition will not identify it's a reverse effect movie. It will give you the timestamp follows the video clip you feed in.